# vuejs start a timer for every record

Tags: vue.js

I have this component rendered, I need to tell the users how much time remaining for each record displayed

I couldn't get anything worked out, I don't know any legible ways to work it out, so just trying calling out methods. I tried child components too but no avail.

```
<template>
<div>

<ul  v-for="question in questions">

 {{init_timer(secs)}}
 {{start_timer()}}
     <li>

                      <a href="#" id="user-profile-text-link">{{question.name}}</a>
                      <span class="question_clock">Validity :  -- counter : {{time_remaining}}
</span> </small>

            </li>



           </ul>

  </div>




</template>

<script>


    export default {

    data: function(){
        return {
            questions: [],
            time_remaining : 1
        };
    },

         methods: {

           init_timer: function(secs) {
              this.time_remaining = secs
           },
            start_timer: function() {
              console.log('startiem')
              setTimeout(function () {  this.time_remaining -= 1 }.bind(this), 1000)



           },


          }
        ,
        created: function(){

            $.getJSON('/questions/json', function(response){
             this.questions = response
          }.bind(this ));
        },


    }
</script>
```

any help is much appreciated

Comment: You have placed the v-for at the wrong line. You need to write v-for in the <li> tag, v-for repeats the tags to which you have attached it.

Comment: This plugin offers help just for your case https://github.com/reinerBa/Vue-Interval in the Demo.js file is a similar use case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote a quick `timer` component that might accomplish what you want.

```
Vue.component("timer", {
  props: {
    interval: {
      type: Number,
      default: 1
    },
    initial: {
      type: Number
    }
  },
  template: `
    <span>{{current}}</span>
  `,
  data() {
    return {
      current: this.initial,
      timerInterval: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onInterval() {
      this.current = this.current -= this.interval
      if (this.current <= 0) {
        clearInterval(this.timerInterval)
        this.current = 0
      }
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    setInterval(this.onInterval, this.interval * 1000)
  }
})
```

Basically, you set the `initial` property which is the time allowed in seconds and the timer will update the DOM every `interval` seconds.

Here is an example.

```js
console.clear()

const questions = [{
    name: "What is your name?",
    time: 30
  },
  {
    name: "What is your quest?",
    time: 50
  },
  {
    name: "What is your favorite color?",
    time: 20
  },
  {
    name: "What is the airspeed velocity of an unladen swallow?",
    time: 10
  },

]

Vue.component("timer", {
  props: {
    interval: {
      type: Number,
      default: 1
    },
    initial: {
      type: Number
    }
  },
  template: `
    <span>{{current}}</span>
  `,
  data() {
    return {
      current: this.initial,
      timerInterval: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onInterval() {
      this.current = this.current -= this.interval
      if (this.current <= 0) {
        clearInterval(this.timerInterval)
        this.current = 0
      }
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    setInterval(this.onInterval, this.interval * 1000)
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: function() {
    return {
      questions: [],
      time_remaining: 1
    };
  },
  created: function() {
    setTimeout(() => this.questions = questions, 100)
    // $.getJSON('/questions/json', function(response){
    //   this.questions = response
    // }.bind(this ));
  },

})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.2.6/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="question in questions">
      <a href="#" id="user-profile-text-link">{{question.name}}</a>
      <span class="question_clock">
        <timer :initial="question.time"></timer>
      </span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```